# How to replace if, else statement in opencart 1.5.x using vQmod

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

I have the following code:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
        $filter = $this->request->get['filter'];
} else {
        $filter = '';
}
```

I want to replace it with:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['attribute'])) {
        $filter = $this->request->get['attribute'];
} else {
        $filter = '';
}
```

I have tried the following in vQmod folder:

```
<operation info="After filter request, add attribute request">
            <search position="Replace"><![CDATA[
            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            if (isset($this->request->get['attribute'])) {
                    $filter = $this->request->get['attribute'];
            }
            ]]></add>
</operation>
```

I checked the vQmod log files and am getting the error: `SEARCH NOT FOUND`
Can anyone help me to tell me what I have to use in `if` statement replacement.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be just to replace both of the `get['filter']` values like so

```
<operation>
    <search position="replace"><[CDATA[get['filter']]]></search>
    <add><[CDATA[get['attribute']]]></add>
</operation>
```

Comment: yes it is, but your solution also replace this one `$this->data['filter']` that is using in `.tpl` file and i don't want to replace this one.

Answer (score 0):

i tried to use `offset` into my search attribute like `<search position="Replace" offset="2">` but it produce some other error so i decide to use single line search like the following :

```
            <operation>
                    <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
                    if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) { 
                    ]]></search>
                    <add><![CDATA[
                    if (isset($this->request->get['attribute'])) {
                    ]]></add>
            </operation>
            <operation>
                    <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
                    $filter = $this->request->get['filter'];
                    ]]></search>
                    <add><![CDATA[
                    $filter = $this->request->get['attribute'];
                    ]]></add>
            </operation>
```

**Hope it helps someone else like me**